# I want to Apply Filters to the recorded Video without using any third Party Framework .I had tried to use CIfilter to CAlayer but its not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, core-image, cifilter

I want to Apply Filters to the Prerecorded Video without using using any third Party Framework How can I do It.I had tried to use CIfilter to CAlayer but its not Working.Here is my code:

```
 CALayer *effectlayer=[CALayer layer];
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone"
                                  keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey,effectlayer,
                        @"inputIntensity", @.5, nil];


    [effectlayer setFilters:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:filter, nil]];

    CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CALayer *videoLayer=[CALayer layer];
    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
    [parentLayer addSublayer:overlayLayer];

    [parentLayer addSublayer:overlayLayero];
    [parentLayer addSublayer:effectlayer];
```

Comment: please be more specific then "is not working". is there a compile or runtime error, if yes, then edit your question to add it.

Comment: Please tell me you solved it, It made me crazy!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for my Answer :

```
// 1 - set up the overlay
CALayer *overlayLayer = [CALayer layer];
UIImage *overlayImage = nil;


overlayImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your Image name"];


[overlayLayer setContents:(id)[overlayImage CGImage]];
overlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
[overlayLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

// 2 - set up the parent layer
CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
[parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer:overlayLayer];

// composiontion is instance of your AVMutableVideoComposition
composition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool
                             videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];
```